# Div fade in after other a href Div's are clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to have a Div fade in after the user clicks two other divs.

This is what I have so far but I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong. I can't seem to get the div to fade in even if only one div is clicked let alone two. Any help would be appreciated! thank you so much.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#video_overlays').hide();
$('#video_overlays').fadeIn(9000);
$('#video_overlaysanswer').hide();
$('#video_overlaysanswer').fadeIn(18000);
$('#video_overlaysanswer1').hide();
$('#video_overlaysanswer2').hide();
$('#video_overlaysanswer2').fadeIn(18000); });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("video_overlaysanswer").click(function() {
    var index = $(this).closest("li").index();
    $("video_overlaysanswer1").eq(index).fadeIn("slow");
    return false; // prevents navigation to #
});
})
</script>



<div id="video_overlays">
This is where text is
</div>


<div id="video_overlaysanswer">
<a href="#"> answer 1</a> 
</div>

<div id="video_overlaysanswer2">
<a href="#"> answer 2</a> 
</div>

<div id="video_overlaysanswer1">
<a href="#"> the answer that I want to fade in once the other two div's are clicked     </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know if this is a transcription error or not, but `$("video_overlaysanswer")` and `$("video_overlaysanswer1")` are looking for *element types* (like `select` or `div`), not for an element by *id*.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#video_overlays').hide();
$('#video_overlays').fadeIn(500);
$('#video_overlaysanswer').hide();
$('#video_overlaysanswer').fadeIn(500);
$('#video_overlaysanswer1').hide();
$('#video_overlaysanswer2').hide();
$('#video_overlaysanswer2').fadeIn(500); 

$("#video_overlaysanswer,#video_overlaysanswer2").click(function() {
    $("#video_overlaysanswer1").fadeIn("slow");
    return false; // prevents navigation to #
});
});
```

Try code above.It works fine.Now implement different click event fo buttons.hope this helps.
http://jsfiddle.net/szr9vpv5/

Comment: hi thanks a bunch! but how can I now get it so it shows up after both of the divs are clicked? instead of just one? I guess I'm not too sure what implement set up different div's mean. Thank you a bunch!

Comment: Just add another id to click event.I've updated code.Now both links open the fadein the same answer div.

Comment: well i suppose the thing is is that I only want the answer to only show up after both links are clicked. if that makes sense?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/szr9vpv5/6/ try this one maybe it's not best approach but it works.